# Error with using AzureML and randomForest()

Tags: r, azure, predict

I developed a classification model from `randomForest()`, then sent the model to the Azure cloud using `publishWebService()`. Then when I try to use `consume()`, I get the following error:

> Error: AzureML returns error code:
>   HTTP status code : 400
>   AzureML error code  : LibraryExecutionError
>
> Module execution encountered an internal library error.
>   The following error occurred during evaluation of R script: R_tryEval: return error: Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
>     no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('randomForest.formula', 'randomForest')"

Does anyone know how to help me with the above error message. Thanks.

Comment: Your error says it all. You are not loading the randomForest library on AzureML when trying to make predictions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually for randomForest use the predict function as

```
predict(model, newdata=inputdata, type = "prob")
```

This works

Comment: If the model is from mlr package unwrap above will not work